# Adding a Package breaks the Build

Tags: android, node.js, npm, react-native

I created a React Native App. I have Android SDK 23 installed as prescribed, ran `react-native init myapp` then `react-native start` and `react-native run-android`.

Everything works perfect.

Now I wanted to add a Module: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient

I did as it is described there. `npm install react-native-linear-gradient --save` and then `react-native link`. When I now want to run `react-native start` and `react-native run-android` I get:

```
 ERROR  EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 
'C:\Users\User\Documents\myapp\android\app\build\generated\source\r\debug\android\support\v7'
{"errno":-4048,"code":"EPERM","syscall":"lstat","path":"C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\myapp\\android\\app\\build\\generated\\source\\r\\debug\\android\\support\\v7"}
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\Users\User\Documents\myapp\android\app\build\generated\source\r\debug\android\support\v7'
```

I have also tried the manual way but again the same mistake. I have my terminal run as administrator so I don't know why he can't delete the path..

Comment: try `npm cache clean`

Comment: @vinayr now I get this Error:* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> java.io.IOException: Could not delete path 'C:\Users\User\Documents\myapp\android\app\build\generated\source\r\debug\com\facebook\fbui'.

Comment: try `cd android && ./gradlew clean`

Comment: Thank you so much!! Now it works :).

Comment: @vinayr can you give some context as to why ./gradlew clean would fix this? Would love to know just for my knowledge!